# Combine Two Columns Into One DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have what I think is kind of an interesting date/time problem in C#.

I wrote code that was recently discovered to have a bug. I was using the shift start and end time for when a shift occurred. I used `shiftStartTime` and `shiftEndTime` in my datatable to figure out how long a shift lasted.

```
<shiftStartTime>2023-01-27T06:00:00</shiftStartTime>
<shiftEndTime>2023-01-27T14:00:00</shiftEndTime>
<actualShiftStartTime>06:07:00</actualShiftStartTime>
<actualShiftEndTime>14:01:00</actualShiftEndTime>
```

What I should have been doing is combining `shiftStartTime` date and `actualShiftStartTime` time and `shiftEndTime` date and `actualShiftEndTime` to come up with the correct start and end time of the shift. And then the thought occurred to me is what if `shiftStartTime` was 2200 and they didn't actually start the shift until after midnight. But this is how I was figuring duration. I am trying to incorporate the two fields into this and I am really struggling. If anyone has ideas I would be so grateful.

```
TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(theTimecardDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ShiftEndTime"].ToString())
                            .Subtract(DateTime.Parse(theTimecardDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ShiftStartTime"].ToString()))
                            .Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Int32.Parse(theTimecardDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["lessLunchMin"].ToString())));
```

```
var dtCreated = DateTime.Parse(theTimecardDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ShiftStartTime"].ToString()).ToString("M/d/yyyy h:mmtt", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));

var dtEnded = DateTime.Parse(theTimecardDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ShiftEndTime"].ToString()).ToString("M/d/yyyy h:mmtt", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));

// var LessLunchMin = DateTime.Parse(theTimecardDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["lessLunchMin"].ToString());

TimeSpan hours = (DateTime.Parse(theTimecardDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ShiftEndTime"].ToString())
                 .Subtract(DateTime.Parse(theTimecardDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ShiftStartTime"].ToString())));
```

Comment: You are struggling because the problem is ill-defined. Yes, you are absolutely right that it's possible that a shift starting at 2023-01-27 22:00 was actually started at 2023-01-28 00:10. But wait, if actualShiftStartTime is 00:10, how do you know it was 01-28 00:10 (2 hours 10 min late) and not 01-29 00:10 (1 day 2 hours 10 min late)? You know it because you made an implicit assumption that a shift is started no later than X hours after the shift start time. I don't see that assumption in your code, so how is C# supposed to know about it? Just something to think about.

Comment: And some practical advice: In your code, you mix three things (a) parsing string datetimes to actual datetimes, (b) formatting actual datetimes as strings, (c) the actual business logic you are trying to implement. (a) and (b) create so much noise that it is almost impossible to see/work on (c). So here's my advice: Do (a) first. Then do (c) in a separate method, working solely with DateTime values. Write unit tests for (c). As soon as you are convinced (c) works, do (b). Otherwise, your code will be a mess unreadable for anyone else (including you in 2 months).

Comment: You should be using the ACTUAL times and not the shift times.  If somebody is late or has to leave early that should not be paid for time not worked.